# DisplayMessage Error "Does not exist"

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web

Below is the code. Where it says "DisplayMessage" is where I have a problem.

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMail();
        DisplayMessage.Text = "Thank you for the comment! Please hit the 'Return to Main Page' to return to the Main Page!";
        DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
        txtPhone.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtComment.Text = "";
    }
```

Am I missing a resource of some sort? Here's what I'm using at the moment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your error says?

Comment: is DisplayMessage a control in the markup aspx page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you downloaded this code from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/371417/Send-Mail-Contact-Form-using-ASP-NET-and-Csharp).  The example on the main page doesnt appear to line up with the code in the actual solution.  Try changing `DisplayMessage` to `lblMsgSend` and see if that fixes it.

Better yet, view the `ContactControl.ascx` files and look for the label ID:

```
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMsgSend" runat="server" Visible="false" />
</p>
```

Comment: Your answer made me see my solution. Thank you! I had forgotten to put the label in my page.